# Get the Author Name in Joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla, alias, author

How do I get the authors name of the current article in Joomla 2.5?

I tried using this code but its giving me number;

```
$id = JRequest::getInt('id');
$article =& JTable::getInstance('content');
$article->load($id);
$article_author = $article->created_by;
echo $article_author;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like this

```
//this method of getting requested variable is deprecated 
$id = JRequest::getInt('id');

//use JFactory::getApplication()->input instead of JRequest::getInt()

$id = JFactory::getApplication()->input->getInt('id')
$article = JTable::getInstance('content');
$article->load($id);

//get user id which create the article
$created_user_id = $article->created_by;

//fetch user
$user = JFactory::getUser($created_user_id);
$article_author = $user->name;
echo $article_author;
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: don't forget you don't need to use `&` ;)

Comment: And please change to `JFactory::getApplication()->input->getInt('id')` instead of `$id = JRequest::getInt('id')`.
JRequest is deprecated.